# How do I enable 'highlight to copy' feature on CentOS6

Tags: linux, centos

How do I enable 'highlight to copy' feature on CentOS6, and middlemouse click to paste.

I thought this is a standard feature for linux distros

Comment: Strictly speaking, highlighting _doesn't_ copy to the clipboard but instead populates a [selection buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection).

Answer (score 0):

It's the standard feature of X window, nothing to do with Linux

So if you didn't install X Window, say you chose Wayland, maybe you won't be able to use that feature on Linux.

I googled a little bit for you but I ain't see nobody met such kind of problem before, good luck.